# Using mySQL data with ListView

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

For three days, I'm trying to use mySQL data to implement my ListView. I succeed to have my data using php request, nevertheless there are some problems with the fact that my app takes some times to receive the data from the network...
So, when my listView should be implement, the arraylist is empty, and it doesn't work...

I tried some solutions like "AsyncTask" but I don't know how to use it in my way.

I really hope somebody could help me, i'm lost !

my "repertoire.java":

```
package com.example.joignabilite;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.joignabilite.ContactAdapter.ContactAdapterListener;

public class Repertoire extends Activity implements ContactAdapterListener {

    // Mettre l'adresse du script PHP
    // Attention localhost ou 127.0.0.1 ne fonctionnent pas. Mettre l'adresse IP local.
    public static final String strURL = "http://192.168.0.13/Bouygues/repertoire.php";
    static ArrayList<Contact> listP;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_repertoire);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String infoContact = getServerData(strURL);
                System.out.println("1" + infoContact);
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("2" + listP);
        //Récupération de la liste des Contacts
        //listP = Contact.getAListOfContact();
        //Création et initialisation de l'Adapter pour les Contacts
        ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, listP);
        //Ecoute des évènements sur votre liste
        adapter.addListener(this);
        //Récupération du composant ListView
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.repertoire_nom);
        //Initialisation de la liste avec les données
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Changement d'activité
        final Button autreDestinataireButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.autre_destinataire);

        autreDestinataireButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Repertoire.this, ContactManuel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onClickNom(Contact item, int position) {
        /*Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Personne");

        builder.setMessage("Vous avez cliqué sur : " + item.nom + "    Son numéro est : 0" + item.numero);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Oui", null);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Non", null);
        builder.show(); */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Repertoire.this, ChoixTemps.class);
        startActivity(intent);      

    }

    public static void ajouterContact(String nom, long numero){
        listP.add(new Contact(nom,numero));
        System.out.println(listP);
    }

    private String getServerData(String strURL) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        String returnString = "";

        // Envoie de la commande http
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convertion de la requÃªte en string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            System.out.println(result);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // Parse les donnÃ©es JSON
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            //Suppression de l'url
            returnString="";
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Affichage ID_ville et Nom_ville dans le LogCat
                Log.i("log_tag","Nom: "+json_data.getString("nom")+
                        ", Numero: "+json_data.getLong("numero")
                );

                listP.add(new Contact(json_data.getString("nom"), json_data.getLong("numero")));

                // RÃ©sultats de la requÃªte
                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return returnString; 
    }


}
```

my "activity_repertoire.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".Repertoire" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/repertoire"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <include android:id="@+id/header"
             layout="@layout/header_mobile"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:text="@string/destinataire"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/repertoire_nom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding" >
        </ListView>

        <Button android:id="@+id/autre_destinataire"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/buttontype1"
                android:text="@string/autre_destinataire" />

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My LogCat:

```
05-12 02:36:50.625: D/memalloc(2205): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5c58e000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:66
05-12 02:36:50.795: I/System.out(2205): 2null
05-12 02:36:50.795: D/AndroidRuntime(2205): Shutting down VM
05-12 02:36:50.795: W/dalvikvm(2205): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab2210)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joignabilite/com.example.joignabilite.Repertoire}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.example.joignabilite.ContactAdapter.getCount(ContactAdapter.java:33)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:464)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.example.joignabilite.Repertoire.onCreate(Repertoire.java:56)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
05-12 02:36:50.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     ... 11 more
05-12 02:36:52.185: I/System.out(2205): [{"nom":"Bob","numero":"243651874"},{"nom":"Alice","numero":"751489525"}]
05-12 02:36:52.225: I/log_tag(2205): Nom: Bob, Numero: 243651874
05-12 02:36:52.235: W/dalvikvm(2205): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab2210)
05-12 02:36:52.245: I/Process(2205): Sending signal. PID: 2205 SIG: 9
05-12 02:36:52.415: D/dalvikvm(2308): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 35K, 4% free 13167K/13663K, paused 20ms
05-12 02:36:52.415: I/dalvikvm-heap(2308): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.705MB for 1858832-byte allocation
05-12 02:36:52.445: D/dalvikvm(2308): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 14981K/15523K, paused 14ms
05-12 02:36:52.485: D/dalvikvm(2308): GC_CONCURRENT freed 454K, 6% free 14627K/15523K, paused 1ms+2ms
```

My ContactAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.joignabilite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Une liste de Contacts
    private List<Contact> mListP;

    //Le contexte dans lequel est présent notre adapter
    private Context mContext;

    //Un mécanisme pour gérer l'affichage graphique depuis un layout XML
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> aListP) {
          mContext = context;
          mListP = aListP;
          mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        }

    public int getCount() {
          return mListP.size();
        }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
          return mListP.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              LinearLayout layoutItem;
              //(1) : Réutilisation des layouts
              if (convertView == null) {
                //Initialisation de notre item à partir du  layout XML "Contact_layout.xml"
                layoutItem = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);
              } else {
                layoutItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;
              }

              //(2) : Récupération des TextView de notre layout      
              TextView tv_Nom = (TextView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.repertoire_item);

              //(3) : Renseignement des valeurs       
              tv_Nom.setText(mListP.get(position).nom);

              //On mémorise la position de la "Contact" dans le composant textview
              tv_Nom.setTag(position);

              //On ajoute un listener
              tv_Nom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Lorsque l'on clique sur le nom, on récupère la position de la "Contact"
                    Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();

                    //On prévient les listeners qu'il y a eu un clic sur le TextView "TV_Nom".
                    sendListener(mListP.get(position), position);

                }

              });

              //On retourne l'item créé.
              return layoutItem;
            }   

        /**
         * Interface pour écouter les évènements sur le nom d'une Contact
         */
        public interface ContactAdapterListener {
            public void onClickNom(Contact item, int position);
        }

        //Contient la liste des listeners
        private ArrayList<ContactAdapterListener> mListListener = new ArrayList<ContactAdapterListener>();
        /**
         * Pour ajouter un listener sur notre adapter
         */
        public void addListener(ContactAdapterListener aListener) {
            mListListener.add(aListener);
        }

        private void sendListener(Contact item, int position) {
            for(int i = mListListener.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                mListListener.get(i).onClickNom(item, position);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: paste your code for `ContactAdapter`

Comment: I put it but I think the problem is focus on the onCreate() of my Repertoire.java ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mListP` inside `ContactAdapter` is **null** that's why causing `NullPointerException`.

**Reason**: you need to initialize `listP` before creating a new object of `ContactAdapter` in `onCreate` method of your activity class.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't this error anymore, however I always can't see my contact in my ViewList. I tried to add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in my thred (in onCreate) but it not refresh the listView, I have:

android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Yes, you cant call **notifyDataSetChanged** from a non UI thread. You should use `runOnUiThread` to dispatch view related calls on your UI thread.

Comment: Ok I think i'm in a good way! I'm trying to use getServerData() in my thread and to use my notifyDataSetChanged in a runOnUiThread but I have now:
"The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread."
Could you be more precise in order to use it in my case ?

Comment: include the code for removing/inserting of your adapter items within **runOnUiThread** too